# I want to Replace a word which contains more no of / using vim

Tags: linux

I want to replace this word `/BGL/HUG/LIK/` to `/TOM/GUY/MAP/` using vim editor I have tried `%s/` commands it's not working please give some better solutions.

Comment: I assume that you want to replace a string containing the character `/` with another string, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the separator `/` after `%s` with any character, so you can choose one that is not included in your source text, e.g.

```
%s,/BGL/HUG/LIK/,/TOM/GUY/MAP/,g
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In this case feel free to mark the answer as correct.